# Given 2 points on a rigid body, how to mathematically obtain the new position when one of the point is moved in space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

A rigid body in space is defined by a point Xm (xm,ym,zm) and an orientation specified by vector N (na,nb,nc). The body has, on it, another point X1(x1,y1,z1) rigidly constrained to Xm. If the Body is moved to a new position and orientation X’m (x’m,y’m,z’m) and N’(n’a,n’b,n’c), find X’1(x’1, y’1,z’1), the new position of X1 assuming rigidity of the constraint is maintained?

Comment: In order to answer to this question, you have to specify in which way the vector N defines the orientation. For me an orientation is an orthogonal matrix $R$ (or three Euler angles).

Comment: Suppose $N=(1,0,0)$ and the body includes the three points $X_m$, $A = X_m+aN$ and $X_1 = X_m+(0,1,0)$. If the meaning of $N$ is "the direction toward $A$", so that the movement and reorientation of the body takes $X_m$ to $X'_m$ and takes $A$ to $X'_m+aN'$, there is still the possibility that the reorientation rotated the body by some unspecified amount around the axis $X'_mA'$. So $N$, defined this way, is not sufficient to specify an orientation; but two vectors would be sufficient. Alternatively, you might be able to encode rotation in the magnitude of $A$, but you'd have to say how.

Comment: @guestDiego na,nb,nc are cosines of the three Euler angles.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. I will try to write a (partial) answer

Comment: $\cos(1) = \cos(-1)$ but rotating by $1$ radian about the last axis gives a different result than rotating by $-1$ radian. Or do you mean something different than I do by Euler angle? Please edit the question to give a more complete description of how $N$ defines the orientation. You might consider giving an example of an actual rotation of the object.

Answer (score 1):

(Sketch) So let $\bf N$ represent the vector defined by the three Euler angles. *Assume* you know how to calculate the rotation matrix $R_{\bf N}$ associated to  $\bf N$ (which can be quite involved!). At that point the solution is simple:
$$
\bf X_1'=\bf X_m'+R_{\bf N'}R_{\bf N}^\top\cdot (\bf X_1-\bf X_m),
$$
where $(\cdot)^\top $ is the transposition.

Comment: This works if $\mathbf N$ uniquely defines a rotation matrix. Based on OP's comments, I'm not convinced that it does (though if it doesn't, that is a flaw in the question rather than in this answer).

Comment: Of course one has to admit that N,  in some way, uniquely defines the rotation matrix. Otherwise the problem makes no sense. One needs three parameters for that (3 Euler angles for example). The author spoke about cosine of Euler angles. That could be indeed  problematic (I agree with you) inasmuch as the cosines do not identify uniquely angles...

Comment: Yes, that's my point exactly. I'm not sure the problem makes sense the way the asker intends it. (But if we can make sense of the problem then your answer works fine, of course.)